# org-mode capturing note to entry at point

Tags: org-mode

I'm often perusing my org-mode agenda and want to add a quick note with timestamp to the entry I'm on.  I want to create a new capture template and set `function-finding-location` to use the entry where my point is.  It seems like there would be a pre-existing function I could use for that, something like `entry-at-point`?  Could someone help point me?

Answer (score 1):

see [10.1.3.2 Template expansion.](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion)

you can add special “%-escapes” in your templates.

to add timestamp: %t or %T;

to record the location where your entry is: %a.

Comment: I would never have gotten that from "Annotation, normally the link created with org-store-link." (the description for %a).  I'm not understanding how this will determine the location of the note but I'll mess with that option and report back.